# What three manifolds can be represented as a fibration of a circle over a Riemann surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

In ["Supersymmetric Field Theories on Three-Manifolds"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3388), the metric for a general circle fibration over a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ (a Seifert manifold) is given on page 5 by 
$$
ds^2=\Omega(z,\bar{z})(d\psi + a(z,\bar{z})dz+ \bar{a}(z,\bar{z})d\bar{z})^2 + c(z,\bar{z})dzd\bar{z}.
$$

My question is, what kind of manifolds are described by metrics where $a(z,\bar{z})=\bar{a}(z,\bar{z})=0$? It seems that these are essentially manifolds which are related to $S^1\times \Sigma$ by a local rescaling. But are there familiar examples of manifolds, such as $S^3$, that can be described by such metrics?

Comment: Do you assume $\Sigma$ has genus $g>1$, i.e., carries the hyperbolic metric?  If not, then S^3 via the Hopf fibration is an example.  The unit tangent bundle of $\Sigma$ is another example, as are the unit vector of any Hermitian line bundle on $\Sigma$.

Comment: I make no assumption on the genus. May I know what are the explicit metrics for the latter two spaces?

Comment: Basically you use the Levi-Civita connection on $\Sigma$ to put a Riemannian metric on the tangent bundle and restrict that to those tangent vectors having unit length.  In other words, you can think of $\mathrm{d}\psi+a(z,\bar{z})\,\mathrm{d}z+\bar{a}(z,\bar{z})\,\mathrm{d}\bar{z}$ as defining the covariantly constant circle fibre direction (along the circle), $\Omega(z,\bar{z})$ as just a scaling factor, and $c(z,\bar{z})\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}\bar{z}$ as the metric on $\Sigma$.

Comment: Sorry, but in my question I am interested in the case where $a=\bar{a}=0$. Can the metrics you describe satisfy this criterion?